# Data strangely synchronized between viewmodel and $sessionStorage

Tags: angularjs, watch, session-storage

I am storing a list of objects in the `$sessionStorage`. Then in one of my controllers I get the value of that list and display it on the page and the user can delete its items.

The problem is, that when the user deletes one item of that list from the view model, it gets also deleted from the `$sessionStorage` which I don't want.

Here is my controller's code

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  myModule.controller('infoCollecteArticlesController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$sessionStorage', 'global_factory', 'infoCollecteArticlesFactory',
  function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $sessionStorage, global_factory, infoCollecteArticlesFactory) {
    var vm = this;

    /*
    * PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
    */

    // Delete a URL from the vm
    vm.deleteUrl = function(index) {
        vm.web_urls.splice(index, 1);
    }

    // Watch sessionStorage
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return $sessionStorage.currentCommuneData;
    }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            vm.web_urls = newVal.web_information.web_urls;
            vm.filters = newVal.web_information.stop_list;
        }
        else {
            window.location.replace("test.html");
        }
    }, true);
}
]);
})();
```

Comment: try `vm.web_urls = angular.copy(newVal.web_information.web_urls);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vm.web_urls = newVal.web_information.web_urls;`

**This line directly refer to the object of the sessionStorage variable with the same memory location.**

So, even of you remove the  object from `vm.web_urls`, the data from sessionStorage is getting deleted.

Instead copy the object but not reference using

```
vm.web_urls = angular.copy(newVal.web_information.web_urls);
vm.filters = angular.copy(newVal.web_information.stop_list);
```

So change your `watch` function to,

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
        return $sessionStorage.currentCommuneData;
    }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            vm.web_urls = angular.copy(newVal.web_information.web_urls);
            vm.filters = angular.copy(newVal.web_information.stop_list);
        }
        else {
            window.location.replace("test.html");
        }
    }, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of web_urls to disconnect bindings if any

```
// Delete a URL from the vm
    vm.deleteUrl = function(index) {
        vm.web_urls = angular.copy(vm.web_urls).splice(index, 1);
    }
```

Also you may copy newVal so that bindings are disconnected

```
vm.web_urls = angular.copy(newVal.web_information.web_urls);
```